# Firestore Date to UTC seems a wrong

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase firestore and notice a bit weird, for me, issue with dates. I know dates are saved as UTC in firestore, but maybe are some of misundertanding of js Date by me

my timezone: -3

I am using this piece of data to illustrate issue.

```js
doc.update({
    'date_handover_prune':  admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(pruneDateToEnd(new Date('2022-06-10'))),
    'date_handover_prune_with_time':  admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(pruneDateToEnd(new Date('2022-06-10 10:00:00'))),
    'date_handover_raw': admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date('2022-06-10')),
    'date_handover_raw_with_time':  admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date('2022-06-10 10:00:00')),
})
```

and my `pruneDateToEnd` is this

```js
const pruneDateToEnd = (date: Date) => {
  const newDate = new Date(date)
  newDate.setHours(23)
  newDate.setMinutes(59)
  newDate.setSeconds(59)

  return newDate
}
```

when view it on firestore i found a bit weird results

```js
date_handover_prune: 2022-06-10 02:59:59.000
// weird cause day remains 10, as far as i know the day should change to 11 no?
// why only the time part seems to be converted to UTC?
```

```js
date_handover_prune_with_time: 2022-06-11 02:59:59.000
// thats ok
```

```js
date_handover_raw: 2022-06-10 00:00:00.000
// weird too, should it not set time to 03:00:00 ? like date_handover_raw_with_time that go from 10:00:00 to 13:00:00.000 ?
```

```js
date_handover_raw_with_time: 2022-06-10 13:00:00.000
// thats ok
```

what am I missing

Comment: Because of an error in the early specs, a Javascript `Date('YYYY-MM-DD')` that does not include time is assumed to be in UTC, and a `Date('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')` that does include time is assumed to be in local time.  I'm not sure that completely explains your issues, but that's part of it.

Comment: If you want an accurate timestamp, you're going to have to provide a timezone to give meaning to the time string.  JavaScript doesn't know how to interpret the string you're giving it, so it's making an assumption.  Firestore timestamps are always stored in UTC, so if you want to display the timestamp later, you're again going to need a timezone that makes sense for the end user reading it.

Comment: If you're constructing dates from known data (year, month, day, etc), avoid string parsing and use `new Date(2022, 5, 10)`